# t-sql : get a single row with parents, children, grandchildren... n children

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns: `ID, ParentID`

i want to make a new table/view that each row includes all the children in all levels to a certain parents...

for example:

```
ParentID  Level_1  Level_2  Level_3 ... Level_n
```

it means that parentID is the parent of Level_1 which is the Parent of level 2 which is the parent of level_3 and so on...

i need to do it with no recursion so no chance to stack overflow...

in T-SQL there's a function called `@@rowcount` which returns the rows i got in the last select so maybe i can use it inside a while loop or something...

the question is how can i know how many columns to construct at the beginning ?
any idea how to access this challenge ?

Comment: Is this a one-time job, or something that needs to be done repeatedly?

Comment: Not being able to use recursion REALLY complicates this...

Comment: Looking foward to seeing this done without recursion, and without PIVOT.  I believe recursion is required to travse the graph of relationships, and I also believe PIVOT is out as you need to know how many levels there are to construct the PIVOT query, as per @pcofre answer.

Comment: hi guys, this is something that can be used over and over...
i dont really know tsql that well and i'm still not sure what's PIVOT table (just what i remember from excel).. but it can be done with a single WHILE loop and got something to do with that @@RowCount function...

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to get is a pivot table, but, in my opinion, this task doesn't belong to the database. I'd rather get a result set with rows and pivot them "externally".

To achieve what I described, in SQL Server 2005+ you can use a Common Table Expression ([here you can find an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665617/how-to-create-an-sql-server-2005-cte-to-return-parent-child-records-for-children), while SQL Server 2000 requires a slightly different approach.

**Note**: although you wrote "no recursion so no chance to stack overflow", you'll still have to proect yourself from infinite loops. I personally use recursion and establish a maximum "depth" for it; when the recursion attempts to go "deeper" than the limit, I stop it and return an error.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by creating a Table Valued Function TVF, that returns the whole tree of an employee with his level as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTree](@EmployeeID int)
RETURNS @Result Table
(   EmployeeID  int,
    IdParent int,
    Lvl int
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @lvl int
    set @lvl=0
    while(@EmployeeID is not null)
    begin
        insert  into @Result
        select  EmployeeID,ManagerID,@lvl
        from    dbo.MyEmployees
        where   EmployeeID=@EmployeeID

        select  @EmployeeID=ManagerID,
                @lvl=@lvl+1
        from    dbo.MyEmployees
        where   EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
    end

    update @Result
    set Lvl = (select MAX(Lvl) from @Result)-Lvl+1
RETURN
END
```

And then simply apply the PIVOT function, to get your output:

```
SELECT [1] AS Lvl1, [2] AS Lvl2, [3] AS Lvl3, [4] AS Lvl4
FROM 
(select a.EmployeeID,b.EmployeeID EID,b.Lvl
from    dbo.MyEmployees a cross apply
        dbo.GetTree(a.EmployeeID) b) p
PIVOT
(MIN (EID)
FOR Lvl IN
( [1], [2], [3], [4] )
) AS pvt
```