# how to show hierarchical data from table with hierarchyid data type in tree view in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, hierarchical-data

I have a table with this structure :

```
 create table shajare (
    node hierarchyid PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
level AS node.GetLevel() PERSISTED,
person_id int Unique,
person_name Nvarchar(30) Not null);
```

and I use this in SQL Server to show all children of a given parent:

```
select * 
from shajare as parent
inner join shajare as child on child.node.IsDescendantOf(parent.node) = 1
where parent.person_id = 12
```

How can I show the children of a parent in a tree view by do not using recursive function or using some thing like that SQL code but by linq ? My boss asked for linq???

Please !!

Comment: can you show and example of the expected output?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You should create VIEW in your DB which will do the recursion (e.g. using Common Table Expression) and query the VIEW from LINQ.

Comment: Your boss is stupid. Linq sometimes easier to use but most of the time slower and take up more resources

Comment: **parent1 --> chid 1,child2**some thing like this please help me even without linq .....

Comment: i create a view and can use it in  visual studio in data gird view . but there is a problem , visual studio 2010 cant identify the hierarchyid  data type, so i made the view without **node** field , there was no problem in showing by grid view but how can i create tree view without **node** field???

Comment: will be possible if create a XML file then read data from it ? how create it?? I have so much stress!!!!!!

Comment: i found a way but with c# i cant understand it good can any one help me and convert it **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37038/Loading-a-TreeView-using-HierarchyID** and one thing more the **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types** do not work what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here to get a parent and all children/grand children and so on back from a sql query (will return the complete tree structure).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14764333/853295